# Difference between company account and MSA account with msal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating an test application with MSAL to see how we can implement it in our products. I stumbeled upon something I can't explain, so I hope someone can explain it to me.

I can configured the application like this on app dev site

[image]

I use msal.js to get an authorization token

[image]

I get redirected to login page as expected, if I try to login with my company account, I don't get to the consent screen and get back following error description:

AADSTS65005: The application 'auth-test' asked for scope 'openid' that doesn't exist on the resource. Contact the app vendor.

If I login with my MSA account, I get to the consent screen and back to my application with an authorization token as expected

So for the same app there's a difference between company account and MSA account? What do I have to do so that I can get with my company account to the consent screen and back to the application with an authorization token?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that *msal.js* requires an *Id Token* provided by *openid* scope which is not added if the application does not have a redirect URL.

Try going back to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, edit your app's registration information, select 'Add Platform', then 'Web'. Then add a redirect URL such as http://localhost.